# Where to start fixing an IO Bottle neck in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, performance, performance-tuning

I recently came across an [interesting article](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts.aspx) that went over using IO statistics to identify the causes of performance issues.  After examining my statistics i came to the determination that i had a "bottleneck in the IO Subsystem".

Unfortunately I don't really know what this means.  From what I've found on the web, throwing some more memory at it might help (i assume because it doesn't have to write to disk as much) but I'm curious if anyone knows of a good approach for determining how to proceed?